# Key column has repeating values. I'm trying to merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I want to merge `DF1` with `DF2` on customerEmail which is common in both but having repetitive values.
DF1

```
 customer_Email  Fraud
 name_0          False
 name_1          True
 name_2          True
 name_3          True
 name_4          False
 name_1          False
```

DF2

```
customer_Email  ID
 name_0           0
 name_1           1
 name_2           2
 name_3           3
 name_4           4
 name_1           5
```

Kindly note the DF1 and DF2 is for example purpose only.

The `customerEmail` is not unique in both the dataframes

So when I join these two tables using `pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='customerEmail', how=left)`, it is filling my target column `Fraud` with random values from the row above it when the same `customerEmail` repeats.

I want my `Fraud` column to have null values when there are duplicates in `customerEmail`.

The `customer_email` is not unique in both the dataframes.

Current output:

```
customer_Email ID     Fraud
 name_0        0      False
 name_1        1      True
 name_2        2      True
 name_3        3      True   
 name_4        4      False
 name_1        5      True
 name_2        0      True
 name_1        1      True
 name_3        2      True
```

Expected output:

```
customer_Email ID     Fraud
 name_0        0      False
 name_1        1      True
 name_2        2      True
 name_3        3      True   
 name_4        4      False
 name_1        5      N/A
 name_2        0      N/A
 name_1        1      N/A
 name_3        2      N/A
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! Could you post your dataframes as in-line code? This way people can copy it directly. You might also read up on how to create [a mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the dataframe currently returned by your code?

Comment: Can you please be more specific and give us some sample data with desired output, not as a screenshot? Maybe you can left join DF1 to DF2 `pd.merge(DF2, DF1, on='customerEmail', how=left)` but that won't give you 'null values when there are duplicate customerEmails'

Comment: Welcome to SO. First please edit your question and remove links to external sites. Post the tables as Code here on the site instead of linking to an external image that might be gone someday so that users can't understand the question anymore. That being said please post an expected output. How do you want the resulting table to look? There is a reason a merge doesn't work so well on data with duplicate entries in the merge column and if you show the expected output, people maybe can give you something that fits better.

Comment: post the data as text not images

Comment: If the first appearance of `name_1` in `DF1` had `Fraud == False` and the second appearance had `True`... would you expect the first (`False`) in your merged df? Or `True` if any of the rows is true in df1?

Comment: The appearance of name_1 is more in DF2 than in DF1 in my real dataset. So I expect when DF2 joins DF1 to have NULL values after the matching is done initially

Comment: show your DF2 as well

Comment: your expected output is wrong, " want my Fraud column to have null values when there are duplicates in customerEmail." but you are taking into account also 'ID'

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? (Assuming `customer_email` is unique in df2):

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['customer_Email'], how="left")
df3["count"] = df3.groupby("customer_Email").cumcount()
df3.loc[df3["count"]>0,"Fraud"] = "N/A"
df3[["customer_Email","Fraud","ID"]]
```

Output:

```
    customer_Email  Fraud   ID
0   name_0          False   0
1   name_1          True    1
2   name_1          N/A     5
3   name_2          True    2
4   name_3          True    3
5   name_4          False   4
6   name_1          N/A     1  
7   name_1          N/A     5
```

Comment: Thanks for trying  the customer_Email is not unique in DF2 as well any other suggestions?

Comment: Thanks  could you please explain a little about the steps you did after merging the dataframes

Comment: You just replace those `customer_Email` `Fraud` values that are not the first with `"N/A"`

Answer (score 0):

" want my Fraud column to have null values when there are duplicates in customerEmail."

so in your expected output you forgot to add `name_4`  in `customerEmail` because its duplicated as well

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'customerEmail':['name0','name1','name2','name3','name4','name1'],
    'Fraud':[False,True,True,True,False,False]
}
                  )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'customerEmail': ['name0', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name1'],
    'ID':[0,1,2,3,4,5]
})


df3=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='customerEmail', how='left')

#here you need to know which customers are duplicated, to fill for them rows in column Fraud
df_duplicates = df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['customerEmail'],keep='last')
print(df_duplicates)
  customerEmail  Fraud  ID
0         name0  False   0
3         name2   True   2
4         name3   True   3
5         name4  False   4
7         name1  False   5
#now for those duplicates fill cells in column Fraud using iloc and np.nan
df_duplicates.loc[:,'Fraud'] = np.nan
print(df_duplicates)
  customerEmail  Fraud  ID
0         name0    NaN   0
3         name2    NaN   2
4         name3    NaN   3
5         name4    NaN   4
7         name1    NaN   5
#so now you have two df's , one df_duplicates with Nans duplicates values above,
#and main df3 with original merged values

#now you need to add those df's using concat , (add column to column )
#but you dont need values with same customerEmail that you used for df_duplicated, so you can delete them using drop_duplicates
result = pd.concat([df3,df_duplicates]).drop_duplicates(subset=['customerEmail','Fraud'])
#after concat True and False values has been coverted to 1.0 and 0 , for we need to change the type to False and True again
result.Fraud = result.Fraud.astype('boolean')
print(result)
  customerEmail  Fraud  ID
0         name0  False   0
1         name1   True   1
3         name2   True   2
4         name3   True   3
5         name4  False   4
6         name1  False   1
0         name0   <NA>   0
3         name2   <NA>   2
4         name3   <NA>   3
5         name4   <NA>   4
7         name1   <NA>   5
```

Comment: Thanks  could you please explain a little about the steps you did after merging the dataframes?.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='customer_Email', how='left')
out.loc[~out['customer_Email'].isin(df2.drop_duplicates(subset='customer_Email', keep=False)['customer_Email'].tolist()), 'Fraud'] = None
out
```

**Gives:**

```
    customer_Email  Fraud   ID
0   name_0  0.0 0
1   name_1  NaN 1
2   name_1  NaN 5
3   name_2  1.0 2
4   name_3  1.0 3
5   name_4  0.0 4
6   name_1  NaN 1
7   name_1  NaN 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) function with `keep=False` to get duplicates emails in df1 and/or df2.
Here is below the code to put N/A for any row with duplicated email in df1 or df2.

```py
df = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on='customerEmail', how='left')
dups_1 = set(DF1.customerEmail[DF1.customerEmail.duplicated(keep=False)])  # get duplicated emails in df1
dups_2 = set(DF2.customerEmail[DF2.customerEmail.duplicated(keep=False)])  # get duplicated emails in df2
dups = dups_1.union(dups_2)    # get duplicated emails in df1 or df2 (you can also use only dups_1 or only dups_2)
df["Fraud"] = df.apply(lambda row: "N/A" if row.customerEmail in dups else row.Fraud, axis=1)  # put N/A if email in dups
```